# d3 graph only show on default tab in a page with multiple tabs

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, graph, tabs

I am currently working on a "DashBoard" project. My goal is to create **a web page** that contains **multiples tabs**. In each tab, there is a graph. My problem now is **the graph ONLY show on the default tab**.
My codes are below

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Metrics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab00')" id="defaultOpen">Summary</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab01')" >January</button>
    ...

    <div id="tab00" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="tab00HBar" onload="horizontalBarChart();"></div> 
    </div>

    <div id="tab01" class="tabcontent">
        <div id="tab01HBar" onload="horizontalBarChart();"></div>
    </div>
    ...

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### script.js

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

function horizontalBarChart(){

d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.dev = d.dev;
        d.value = +d.value;
    });


var axisMargin = 20,
        margin = 20,
        valueMargin = 4,
        width = parseInt(d3.select(".tabcontent").node().getBoundingClientRect().width/2, 10), 
        height = parseInt(d3.select(".tabcontent").node().getBoundingClientRect().height/2, 10),
        barHeight = (height-axisMargin-margin*2)* 0.7/data.length,
        barPadding = (height-axisMargin-margin*2)*0.3/data.length,
        data, bar, svg, scale, xAxis, labelWidth = 0;

max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; });

svg = d3.select("#tab00")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


bar = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

bar.attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("cx",0)
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + margin + "," + (i * (barHeight + barPadding) + barPadding) + ")";
        });

bar.append("text")
        .attr("class", "dev")
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em") //vertical align middle
        .text(function(d){
            return d.dev;
        }).each(function() {
    labelWidth = Math.ceil(Math.max(labelWidth, this.getBBox().width));
});

scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max])
        .range([0, width - margin*2 - labelWidth]);

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(scale)
        .tickSize(-height + 2*margin + axisMargin)
        .orient("bottom");

bar.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+labelWidth+", 0)")
        .attr("height", barHeight)
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return scale(d.value);
        });

bar.append("text")
        .attr("class", "value")
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dx", -valueMargin + labelWidth) //margin right
        .attr("dy", ".35em") //vertical align middle
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d){
            return (d.value+"%");
        })
        .attr("x", function(d){
            var width = this.getBBox().width;
            return Math.max(width + valueMargin, scale(d.value));
        });  

svg.insert("g",":first-child")
        .attr("class", "axisHorizontal")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin + labelWidth) + ","+ (height - axisMargin - margin)+")")
        .call(xAxis);
});}horizontalBarChart();
```

#### style.css

```
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #7186f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
background-color: inherit;
float: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px 16px;
transition: 0.3s;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
display: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: none;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}


.tabcontent {
-webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
animation: fadeEffect 1s; /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* Horizontal Bar */
svg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: center;
}

text {
font: 14px sans-serif;
}
text.value {
font-size: 100%;
fill: white;
}

.axisHorizontal path{
fill: none;
}

.axisHorizontal .tick line {
stroke-width: 1;
stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
fill-opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: My guess is the problem is around `svg.insert("g",":first-child")
            .attr("class", "axisHorizontal")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin + labelWidth) + ","+ (height - axisMargin - margin)+")")
            .call(xAxis);
 });`

Comment: any thoughts, please?